# Permission denied writing to /proc in ubuntu container and host

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that runs fine when in privileged mode.

When not run with privileged, I can't write to a file in /proc

I get permission denied. The file in /proc is created by the container and has w rights for root (The service in the container is running as root)

Can anyone shed light on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the docker-default apparmor profile that did not allow write to /proc

running the container with security-opt apparmor=unconfined resolved the issue